# TypeError: record_club_minutes() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'purchase' and 'fund'

Tags: python, flask

I'm making an app in which students can input their club data and create minutes for their respective clubs. Right now, I'm running into some trouble trying to pass these two variables from one form into another (purchase and fund); it keeps on giving the TypeError above. These variables give the number of entries for a FormField in the form. It's most likely that the error is in generate_minutes(user_id) because when I assigned a fixed integer in record_club_minutes(user_id, club_id, purchase, fund) so that purchase=0 and fund=0, it worked. Any help is greatly appreciated!

**routes.py**

```
@login_required
def generate_minutes(user_id):
    user = User.query.get_or_404(user_id)
    # TODO: use the same form
    form = record_club_name_form(user)
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        # send user to the record_club_minutes
            club = form.club_list.data
            purchitems = form.purchaseitems.data
            funditems = form.funditems.data
            return redirect(url_for('clubs.record_club_minutes', user_id=user_id, club_id=club.id, purchase=purchitems, fund=funditems))
    return render_template('record_club_name.html', title='Record', form=form, user=user)

#THERE MAY BE BUGS HERE 
@clubs.route("/record_minutes/<int:user_id>/<int:club_id>/record", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def record_club_minutes(user_id, club_id, purchase, fund):
    user = User.query.get_or_404(user_id)
    club = Club.query.get_or_404(club_id)
    members = club.members
    form = create_club_minutes_form(club, purchase, fund)
    # form.purchaseform.entries = purchase
    # form.fundform.entries = fund
    if form.validate_on_submit():
            minute = Minutes(club_id=club_id, date=form.date.data, time=form.time.data, location=form.location.data, minute=form.notes.data)
            db.session.add(minute)
            for index, field in enumerate(form.attendance):
                if field:
                    attendance = Attendance(student_name=members[index].firstname + members[index].lastname)
                    minute.attendance.append(attendance)    
            db.session.commit()
            flash('Minutes successfully recorded', 'success')
            return redirect(url_for('clubs.view_club_name', user_id=user.id))
    return render_template('record_minutes.html', title='Record', form=form, user=user, club=club, members=members)
```

Here is **forms.py** for the *record_club_minutes(user_id, club_id, purchase, fund)* above.

```
def create_club_minutes_form(club, purchase, fund):
    num_members = len(club.members)
    class ClubMinutesForm(FlaskForm):
        date = DateField('Meeting Date (mm/dd/year)',
            validators=[DataRequired(), DateRange(max = date.today())],
            format = '%m/%d/%Y')
        time = TimeField('Meeting Called to Order at')
        location = StringField('Meeting Place',
            validators=[DataRequired()],
            render_kw={"placeholder":"Room # or Area"})
        attendance = FieldList(BooleanField('Here'),
            min_entries=num_members,
            max_entries=num_members)
        purchaseform = FieldList(FormField(PurchaseOrderForms), 
            min_entries=purchase, 
            max_entries=purchase)
        purchasevote = FormField(MotionForms)
        fundform = FieldList(FormField(FundraiserForms), 
            min_entries=fund, 
            max_entries=fund)
        fundvote = FormField(MotionForms)
        notes = TextAreaField('Overview of Meeting', 
            validators=[DataRequired(), Length(min=10, max=500)])
        submit = SubmitField('Submit')

    return ClubMinutesForm()
```

**Traceback**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2463, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2449, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1866, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2446, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1951, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1949, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1935, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_login/utils.py", line 261, in decorated_view
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: record_club_minutes() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'purchase' and 'fund'
```

Comment: You're right. `/record_minutes/<int:user_id>/<int:club_id>/record` should contain `purchase` and `fund` to pass it into your view. Because you named it, that's why you have to put it into your url too.

Comment: Thank you! That makes sense. I fixed it!